# rate app reminder actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I tried looking on stackoverflow for this, but didn't have any luck.

Does anyone have an as3 script that would work for asking a user to rate the app after app launches so many times? Also, How would I code it so once they hit the "already rated it" button, it doesn't ask them again?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Meps. Thinking about the SharedObject class... What if, when the user pressed the quit button it popped up a rate this app message and either they click the link or they click "don't show this again" and if they choose the later, it stores that they don't want this popup seen again in the SharedObject data. Does that make sense? I just really don't want it to popup evertime they close the app and want a "permanent" way to have the app remember.

Comment: Anyone? How would I permanently remove an MC once the user clicks a button? Permanent meaning, they close the app, re-open the app and that MC does not show up again...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store locally some data look for SharedObject class.

But I suppose that your problem have no sense because nobody knows how one user rates application without spreading this info with server-side support.